# Remove header image from WooCommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The page I am talking about: https://www.eddiestech.co.uk/product/manchester-university-sign/

I have been trying to create a WooCommerce shop. I have an item set up, but the image of the product is shown twice. One as a header and one as the product image near the name. I would like to remove the header image. I have seen many CSS things to add that haven't worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
.post-format {
    display: none;
}
```

This is how it looks after adding that code.
[image]

Also, is weird your theme options don't include to remove the featured image.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! 